# Elasticsearch distinct count on nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

According to docs, distinct count can be achieved approximately by using cardinality. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html

I have a large store of data of type like this:

```
{
    {
        "foo": {
            "bar": "a1"
        }
    },
    {
        "foo": {
            "bar": "a2"
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to do a distinct count of "foo.bar" values.

My DSL query:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "number_of_bars": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "bar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

returns "number_of_bars": 0. I was also trying "field": "foo.bar", which results in an error.

Can you tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What was the error ? Cause with field foo.bar it works fine for me. Can you also post the relevant part of the mapping please ? Thx

Comment: The error was:

"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [foo.bar] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."

I don't know what is meant by "relevant part of mapping", sorry I'm new to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this:**

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "number_of_bars": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "foo.bar.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```